# View only lines less / longer then ... characters

Tags: vim, command, character, lines

I'm using a Sed script to view only lines less then or longer then .. characters.
That script doesn't work with both together (when I want to view lines less then p.e. 80 characters and longer then 70 characters).

Does anyone know if there is a simple solution in Vim to view only these lines and empty out (not delete) all other lines

p.e.
a) view only lines less then 75 characters
b) view only lines longer then 80 characters
b) view only lines less then 75 characters and longer then 65 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vimgrep` command:

```
:vimgrep /\v^.{65,75}$/ %
```

It will extract lines which contain `65~75` characters in current file.

---

```
{,74}    =>  less than 75
{81,}    =>  great than 80
{66,74}  =>  between 65 and 75 (exclusively)
```

---

**Update:**

You can use this command to empty unmatched lines:

```
:v/\v^.{65,75}$/s/.*//
```

It'll empty lines which contains `0~64` or `76~+∞` characters.

Comment: thank you, however it is not exact the same as I asked, but very useful to know :)

Comment: Tnx for the update. Very nice but I want to see the lines in the text and empty out all non-matching lines.

Comment: Your update: Yes that does what I want. What does `:v/\v`   and `/s/.*//` do? What would be the code without using "very magic" regex? I think I'll understand it better in that case. I've never worked with very magic.

Comment: `s/.*//` is a sub-command of `v` command. It makes line empty.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) I only added `:let @/= ''` to avoid highlighting of all the matched lines.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to ZyX's answer, this folds away lines that do not contain 65~75 characters.

```
:set foldmethod=expr foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)!~'\\v^.{65,75}$' foldlevel=0
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-two/ has the commandline version (61 and 62 ...)

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang, I use these in my script however there are 2 things they don't do: I can't combine them (that means longer then .. characters and less then .. characters) if I select a block of text, the selection is not the same anymore after applying one of the 2. And.. the sed commands can't empty out all other (not matching) lines.